# No Tests Were Executed when using JUnit5 and Spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, junit5

I have a very simple JUnit test class that I can not run unless I remove `parent spring-boot-starter-parent` from the pom, which wouldn't be a possibility for our production application. The error we get on is No Tests Were Executed and below is the mvp with the parent piece that whenever not commented out would block the tests. If I can get any guidance to know how to fix this please.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
<!-- Piece to be disabled for tests to run -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

<groupId>com.hmhco</groupId>
<artifactId>crs-v2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>crs-v2</name>
<description>Content Recommendation Service V2</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.6.2</junit.jupiter.version>
    <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class TestingTest {

@Test
public void checking() {
    System.out.println("checking------------");
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please show the full code including imports etc. of your test class...

Comment: Remove the dependencies to maven-surefire-plugin in your project and remove the definition of the version for maven-surefire-plugin cause they are already handled in the parent.

Comment: Hi, updated the question having added the import and removed the maven dependency. This had been added just when trying to debug the issue a bit more but whether with or without it I keep getting the same error message still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to that you trying to use a different version of junit jupiter. The version which is predefined by [spring-boot-parent (2.2.4.RELEASE) is 5.5.2](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.2.4.RELEASE/pom). The simplest solution is to remove the versions of junit-jupiter parts (version tag) and use the one which is inherited from spring-boot-parent. The best recommendation I can give is to start with a newer version of Spring Boot (2.3.3.RELEASE most recent one) which uses a more recent version.

If you can't go that way you have to use the `junit-bom` file instead like this:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
```

Then it should work fine. Afterwards you have to use the dependencies without defining the version tag anymore in your pom.xml file.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! Yeah, decreasing Junit to use 5.5.2 instead fixed the issue. Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Adding -DfailIfNoTests=false to the mvn command seems to make it work.

Comment: This will just stop you seeing the error, not fixing it.